# Accessing Web Service using Play Framework 1.2.5

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using **Play framework 1.2.5** in my application in **Eclipse IDE**. I need to access a web service built using **IBM JAX-RPC**. I have got the wsdl file of the web service which I need to access in my applicatiom.

For normal Java EE applications, I used to paste the WSDL in my workspace, generate the files by right clicking the WSDL file => Generate Client option i.e. generating files with the help of Eclipse IDE.

I am not sure how to access the WSDL using Play framework.

I want to know:

1) Where to paste the WSDL file in my workspace?

2) In Play framework how do generate the client (Not sure even if we need this or not in play framework) and access the service methods?

3) Any additional settings needed for accessing the service methods?

Please let me know about this.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way:

Use Play!'s built-in [`play.libs.WS`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.5/play/libs/WS.html) (Link [#2](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/libs#WebServiceclient) and [#3](http://playframework.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/web-services-using-play/)).  You have to create the raw HTTP requests yourself, and parse the XML result from the server yourself.  Of course, this can become a complex task, if the web service interface is complex.

Preferably, you will [create a JAX-RPC client based on your WSDL](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/), and use it from your Play! application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. If i use the first approach i.e. using the Play!'s built-in play.libs.WS then where to place the WSDL file and how to access it? In this case do I need to generate the client? And for the second approach, how to use it from play framework? Can you please explain both the ways in a descriptive way so that I can proceed with it?

Comment: The Web service interface is not that complex, I will prefer to go the first approach. Till date, I have not tried parsing the resquest/response but would love to give it a try. I am not getting any sample code, hence need a sample code on which I can work around. Consider the web service interface contains a `sum` method which will accept two `integer` parameters and will return a `String`. Can you please post a sample code for this? I am running lack of sample code while using this framework as of now :( Please help so that I can dig around.

Comment: I updated the link to the javadoc for play.libs.WS, in my answer.  The previous URL was wrong.  The page contains two samples.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looking at it, I can understand there is not need to paste the WSDL file into workspace , all I need is to pass the URL of the service. But not able to understand how to pass the method name (the method preent in the service interface which I need to invoke for getting the result) and arguments which that method will accept for generating the response? Please let me know about this.

Comment: I have added a link #3, which leads to a blog article written in 2010.  You should be able to rewrite the code in that article to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have made the first implementation work. But still concerned about the second implementation also. Is there some way like rather than creating the client (as you referred in the link) I can take the IDE help for generating the same? In that case, in which directory of my workspace shall I put the WSDL file? Please let me know about this.

Comment: This is not trivial to explain but in NetBeans, you could create an empty Java project, and then right-click on the newly created project, choose new->other->web service->Web service client and then point to your WSDL file.  This will create a web service client, which then can be used from your Play! application.  Please accept my answer if you found it helpful.